# Need workaround for Spock framework issues

Tags: spock

I am facing the following problems while trying to use the  Spock framework

1. Forced to inherit from Specification , is there any way to use annotations instead ?
2. Cannot execute individual tests , only option I found from internet is  @IgnoreRest annotation, is there any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ad 1. There is no way around inheriting directly or indirectly from `Specification` (for good reason).
ad 2. It depends on whether the environment that you are executing tests in (IDE, build tool) allows to execute individual (JUnit) tests.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, I can execute Junit tests individually from Eclipse but I am not finding a way to do the same for spock tests. Can you suggest how to do it.

Comment: Works exactly the same as for JUnit. If it doesn't work for you, maybe your Eclipse or Groovy Eclipse version is too old. (Old Eclipse versions had a known limitation which required to attach the spock-core sources Jar to the spock-core library in order for Eclipse to detect Spock tests.)